# PowerShell unable to write to csv file. Write-Host and Export-Csv produces 2 different outputs

Tags: powershell, csv, converters

Operating System - **Windows 10**

Powershell version - **5.1.15063.1088**

Ok, I'm really trying hard to think logically what can be wrong with this PowerShell script, but apparently can't get an idea and asking for some help. So here is what I'm trying to do, simple as 1+1

If I understood the tutorial correctly, creating an array in PowerShell is like this:

```
$someVariable = "PowerShell", "MowerShell", "HowerShell", "ZowerShell"
```

Then I'm simply trying to write this thing to csv file with comma as delimeter, but firstly give it a try in the console output

```
$someVariable | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

According to [PowerShell 5.1 official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-5.1)

> ...Specifies a delimiter to separate the property values. The default
>   is a comma (,).

So no additional writing that I would like to use comma as delimiter is not required. Once the command `Write-Host $someVariable` is executed, I see this weird output:

```
 "Length" "10" "10" "10" "10"
```

What is this? Am I suppose to see the values of my variable separated with simple comma? So from the numbers I can guess that scripts calculates the amount of alphabet letters in each word -

> P o w e r S h e l l

- contains 10 letters.

Is this the suggested way to calculate the amount of letters in the string (in case I get PowerShell task on my next job interview) using `ConvertTo-Csv` command?

Writing this funky data to the csv file itself leads to more unexpected results:

[image]

Now I'm completely lost what those numbers are...
Is this possible to write my strings as **STRINGS** to the csv file in one line rather then silly numbers?

The desired output is this entry as headers in the csv file:

```
"PowerShell","MowerShell","HowerShell","ZowerShell"
```

Comment: CSV converts objects. Your strings actually have a length property which is why you see that in your output. What is your output supposed to look like? CSVs typically have headers. What is your header?

Comment: Assuming these string values (in the question) are my headers...And isn't $myVariable considered to be an object?

Comment: Everything is an object. ConvertTo-CSV takes each object in a collection and creates a row for each object. This row has a field for each property that the object has. Sort of. In this case you are handing ConvertTo-CSV a collection of String objects. The String object has one property, Length. So what is output is a row that is the header giving the name of each field (Property). In this case there is only the Length field (Property). Then there is a row for each object with the value of that property (Length).

Comment: Oh, and as for why Write-Host and writing to the file present differently, I have know idea. If I do `Write-Host $someVariable` I get `PowerShell MowerShell HowerShell ZowerShell`

Answer (score 1):

The output reads "Length", and has a series of 10's. Each of your strings are 10 characters long (the double quotes aren't factored in).

Length can be calculated many ways. I wouldn't say there is one suggested way, only the ways that fit what you're trying to do.

To get the literal text of what you posted (no headers, etc.) in a csv, try:

```
$someVariable | Out-File foo.csv
```